# Text.Replace in gridview replacing entire cell

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have a gridview that is bound to a sql database. As the user enters data they must indicate whether that cell's information is complete or not. To do this they enter /end/ at the end of their statement and it will automatically change the cell color. If nothing is entered then nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
if (dataItem != null)
            {
                var label = dataItem["Status"].FindControl("Statuslbl") as Label;
                if (label != null)
                {
                    var item = dataItem;
                    var text = label.Text;

                    if (text.Contains("/end/"))
                    {
                        item["Status"].BackColor = Color.Lime;
                        item["Status"].Text = item["Status"].Text.Replace(@"/end/", @"");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item["Status"].BackColor = Color.Salmon;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Instead of just hiding the '/end/' like I need it to, it hides the entire cells contents.

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: If the string contains nothing but "/end/", the result would be blank. Consider performing the operation in an intermediate string field and debug the result. Also, what is the use of @ here?

Comment: @EmmadKareem, can you provide an example of this? and the I saw another post with the @ but it worked the same way with or without it.

Comment: regarding the @, @ could be used to escape chars, so instead of s="c:\\temp\\x.txt"; you could write s=@"c:\temp\x.txt"; but I see no value for it in your case. As for the reason why the value is blank, I am not sure that you are accessing the control's value correctly. See example here:http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent4.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered all I would need to do would be the following to achieve my result:

```
if (text.Contains("/end/"))
                    {
                        item["Test"].BackColor = Color.Lime;
                        item["Test"].Text = label.Text.Replace("/end/", " ");

                    }
```

Really simple, I just needed to use label.Text.